# Why using a pi filter when the applied voltage is DC?

Tags: filter, dac, digital-communications, digital-filter, passive-components

We had to simulate this circuit for an assignment but I still don’t understand why c1, c2, c3 are used in this converter. Are they used as a filter?

[image]

Comment: Looks like these are smoothing capacitors for the power supplies, also to lower their impedance at high frequencies.

Comment: Also, that’s not a pi filter.

Comment: Always, always, always use power supply decoupling (C1 and C3).  Just do it.  If you don't, Bad Things will happen to your circuit.  Bad Weird Things that you can never figure out.

Answer (score 5):

C1 and C3 are "standard" power supply decoupling caps.  Their purpose is to prevent high frequency noise that might be on the power supply rails from coupling onto the output currents.

C2's purpose is a little harder to glean.  The datasheet says nothing (that I could find) as to why this cap is needed or what it does, and I didn't have time to dive into the details of the DAC's internal circuitry to try to figure out what purpose it serves.

Comment: I think it's a cap that's used to control oscillations in the DAC's output.

Comment: C2 is, indeed, a compensation cap for the chip's internal op-amp.  I checked an apparently more comprehensive datasheet (from "this new 1982 edition...")

Comment: I probably have the 1982 edition also, but it would have meant a trek up to the second floor above the garage, which is where a lot of my old data books are stashed (limited room in my den).  Thanks for digging into that.